# Find ObjectId of a user in Azure without module

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I want to find ObjectId of a user, but I can't use Get-AzADUser module as I don't have privilege to install this module.

Get-AzRoleAssignment, Get-AzContext is accessible to me

Is there any other way to find ObjectId of a user with any other module.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated

Comment: Try to install the module with this command `Install-Module -Name Az.Resources -Scope CurrentUser`. If you don't have any errors, try `Get-Command Get-AzADUser` and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @SoySolisCarlos Is Get-AzADUser only command to get ObjectId of a user?

Comment: With the command `Get-AzureADUser` from the module AzureAD, also can get the ObjectId

Comment: How come you can install other modules but not this one?

Comment: you could always call the Graph API directly using HTTP in any case.

Comment: hi Ritesh, is your issue resolved? Have the posts of Rukmini and mine helped with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

During my test, you could run the Azure Powershell task with the [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azaduser?view=azps-9.1.0) `Get-AzADUser -DisplayName <String>` to query the oid.

[image]
[image]

================================================================

**Update on 11/22**

You could also test to use the [az command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/user?view=azure-cli-latest#:%7E:text=Global%20Parameters-,az%20ad%20user%20list,-Edit) of `az ad user list [--display-name]` with local cli.

And it could also be put in Azure DevOps pipeline.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with *Ceeno Qi-MSFT*. Alternatively, you can also use below approach:

***I tried to reproduce the same environment and got the below results:***

To get the ObjectId of a user in Azure, you can make use of **`AzureAD`** module:

```
Install-Module AzureAD -Scope CurrentUser
Connect-AzureAD
```

You can make use of either one of the below commands to retrieve **ObjectID**:

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "XXX@***.onmicrosoft.com"
OR
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq 'XXX@***.onmicrosoft.com'"
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can make use of **Microsoft Graph API to retrieve the Azure AD Users ObjectID**:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ruk@imukhan1998gmail.onmicrosoft.com?$select=id
```

[image]